# How to break multiple while loops

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm making a program that is a game of pick up sticks. I'm still quite confused with the logic of the entire thing. My biggest problem is I have multiple nested while loops and want to end all of them. Heres my code.

x = 1

```
while x == 1:
   sticks = int(input('How many sticks are on the tables (10 to 100): '))


   if sticks not in range(10,101):
        print('Invalid.')
        continue
   while x == 1:
        print('There are',sticks,'sticks on the table.')
        print('Player 1')
        p1 = int(input('How many sticks do you want to remove?'))
        if p1 == sticks:
            print('Player one wins.')
            x == 2
            break
        elif p1 not in range(1,4):
            print('Invalid.')
            continue
        else:
            while x == 1:
                sticks -= p1
                print('There are',sticks,'sticks on the table.')
                print('Player 2.')
                p2 = int(input('How many sticks do you want to remove?'))
                if p2 == sticks:
                        print('Player two wins.')
                        x == 2 
                        break

                elif p2 not in range(1,4):
                    print('Invalid.')
                    continue
                else:
                    sticks -= p2
```

My output continues to prompt player 1 and 2 for input.

I want the program to end after printing "Player _ wins".
Any helps/ tips would be greatly appreciated! Or even a simpler way to write the program.

Comment: You dont need all thosw while x == 1. Since they are all the same, you can put all your code underneath one while loop.

Comment: You should only nest loops if you genuinely need to perform the inner loop every time you iterate over the outer loop.  Just nesting multiple loops for no reason creates artificial problem, as you've already seen.

Answer (score 1):

I always find building a state machine for a multi-player turn-based game helps a lot. Because it provides a clear and easy way to decompose the logic and avoid using a lot of `break` and `continue` or even `goto` in nested loops.

For example, here is a state machine which has 4 states:
[image]

For each state, there's a handler function, it will decide which state to go next(even itself) based on current player, sticks and user input:

```
def initialize():
    global sticks, state
    n = int(input('How many sticks are on the tables (10 to 100): '))
    if n not in range(10, 101):
        print('Invalid. It should be between 10 ~ 100.')
    else:
        state = 'ask_player1'
        sticks = n


def ask_player1():
    global sticks, state
    print('There are', sticks, 'sticks on the table.')
    print('Player 1')
    n = int(input('How many sticks do you want to remove?'))
    if n not in range(1, 4):
        print('Invalid. It should be between 1 ~ 4')
    else:
        sticks -= n
        if sticks == 0:
            print('Player one wins.')
            state = 'end'
        else:
            state = 'ask_player2'


def ask_player2():
    global sticks, state
    print('There are', sticks, 'sticks on the table.')
    print('Player 2')
    n = int(input('How many sticks do you want to remove?'))
    if n not in range(1, 4):
        print('Invalid. It should be between 1 ~ 4')
    else:
        sticks -= n
        if sticks == 0:
            print('Player two wins.')
            state = 'end'
        else:
            state = 'ask_player1'


state_machine = {
    'initialize': initialize,
    'ask_player1': ask_player1,
    'ask_player2': ask_player2,
}

sticks = 0
state = 'initialize'
while state != 'end':
    state_machine[state]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to move the code into a function that returns.  Multi-breaks have been [proposed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/) multiple times and have been [rejected](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html).  You can put this whole code into a function that returns after "Player _ wins", so it doesn't keep running.  Other alternatives are using a flag variable that is set after a player wins and raising an exception that is subsequently handled.

Comment: No, look at the code.  There are way more nested loops than are needed, and OP never needs to break out of more than one loop if properly structured.

Comment: I originally had only one loop . But am having trouble understanding how to reprompt user for input if they enter an invalid value at the 'How many sticks do you want to remove?' point, without using another loop.

Comment: @Tom Karzes, I see lots of problems with the code.  I see some attempts at input validation, which would require a separate loop than the main game.  Either way, the fundamental problem she's describing is how to handle breaking of multiple loops, which isn't always solvable (in the best way) by refactoring the code into a single loop.